# Store data from asynchronous call to a variable in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, deferred, angular-promise

Following is the code in which I am trying to use `promise` to save data from an asynchronous call to a variable but its not working. I am new to promise as I serached and found promise helps in these cases but I am unable to apply, let me know what I am doing wrong here -

```
angular.module("app").controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http, $q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var data = $http.get("/api/events").success(function(response){
    deferred.resolve(response);
    return deferred.promise;
    // ALSO tried return response;
    })
    console.log("DATA--");
    console.log(data);
});
```

**EDIT** -

I am trying to hit **two** APIS -

1) Create array of ids from 1st API hit.

2) Loop to the array for 2nd API hit on id basis.

3) Concatenate some data from array 1 and array2.

More specific case, which I am trying to do  but found to use promise -

http://pastebin.com/ZEuRtKYW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it as follows:

```
$http.get('data.json').success(function (result) {
    $scope.result = result;
}).then(function (data) {
    var result = data.data.key;

    var promises = result.map(function (val) {
        var deffered = $q.defer();

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'data-' + val.id + '.json'
        })
        .success(function (x) {
            deffered.resolve(x);
        })
        .error(function () {
            deffered.reject();
        });

        return deffered.promise;
    });

    $q.all(promises).then(function (result) {
        $scope.resolvedData = result;
    });

});
```

Map all the promises into a promises array based on the result of the first call. Inside this map function create a new promise and resolve it in the success function. Make sure you return the actual promise!

Afterwards you can get all the resolved data with `$q.all(promises)`. This way your calls to the database are not limited to 2. You can do as much calls as you want based on the data retrieved in the first call.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8NmwZqJS5568byw0ibmf?p=preview)

**Edit**: Not sure if you're able to modify the service, but it would be better if you can achieve this with only one call. For instance:

```
get '/api/events' --> returns just the events
get '/api/events?includeDetail=true' --> returns the events + the details of an event
```

Comment: Wow this looks interesting..let me give a try +1

Comment: This looks to be at least on the right lines. Some possible improvements - (a) purge the [Deferred anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns), (b) change `.done()` to `.then()` and purge the first inner `.then()`, (c) use `$http.get()` for the inner requests, (d) rearrange to avoid unnecessary assignments. For some reason I don't understand, `$http.get().then()` delivers more comprehensive data than `$http.get().success()` but the necessary data reduction is quite trivial.

Comment: Do all the above and I end up with ten (10) lines of code, or twelve (12) including the controller wrapper! **[forked Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JN3oDXL1dzxXCwb8xn2T?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

When you get response in asynchronous call, store it in scope variable. Then you can access that scope variable anywhere inside controller.

```
 angular.module("app").controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
         $http.get("/api/events").success(function(response){
         $scope.response = response;     
        })

    });
```

Comment: Are you sure ?? as after return I dont think it will console anything ?

Comment: @Trailcoder, as the response is not available, the console did not show any response.Now as the response is being scope variable. access it in other places.

Comment: Is your problem solved of calling two apis and concatenating response?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done somthing like as:

```
angular.module("app").controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http, $q) {

   var ids = [],
       q1 = $q.defer(), 
       q2 = $q.defer();
       d1 = $http.get("/api/events").success(function(data){
               q1.resolve(data);
               angular.forEach(data, function(id) {
                  ids.push(id); 
               });
            }).error(function(err){
                q1.reject("Ooops!!")
            });

   var promises = [];

   angular.forEach(ids, function(id) {
      var promise = $http.get("/api/events", {id:id})
                    .success(function(data){
                        q2.resolve(data);
                    }).error(function(err){
                        q2.reject("Ooops!!")
                    });
      promises.push(promise);
   });

   $q.all(promises)
     .then(function(values) {        
       console.log(values);
   });
});
```

Comment: Thx for responding actually I need to create an array of ids from this api and then I am trying to hit another api and then the result from another api hit(2nd) I need to concatenate the result for final array..let me know if that works for the case

Comment: Okay then in this case yes you really need to have `$q` and return the promise in the last and you can do this with `$q.all(q1, q2, q3)`.

Comment: yup you got it..I am looking into it but unable to shape it :( kindly let me kow how could I achieve this ?

Comment: more specifically I am trying this http://pastebin.com/6Rk1UqGy but then I found for this I need to use promises

Comment: Thx ..it will really help a novice :)

Comment: Some redundant code in first - this is final what I want to achieve  http://pastebin.com/ZEuRtKYW

Comment: Thx for the help..right now I am integrating your code into mine..will accept it ASAP :)

Comment: I tried this http://pastebin.com/VVCytTTf but its giving an empty array for ids though when I console the inner values are coming

Comment: This won't work, the IDs array will be empty when it reaches the angular.forEach because the IDs are filled inside the $http promise.. Imo this is not a good solution.. + the logic inside the foreach is also not obvious. Why are you mixing up 2 promises? You should use one or the other..